# Issue forcing download of CSV File | PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

Essentially I have the following script that should interpret the data from the query, format as CSV and download the CSV file.

While the data and CSV structure is being generated correctly, the file is not downloading. Instead the data is just being presented on the web page:

```
<?php
 
//Our MySQL connection details.
$host = '';
$user = '';
$password = '';
$database = '';
 
//Connect to MySQL using PDO.
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
 
//Create our SQL query.
$sql = "  ";
 
//Prepare our SQL query.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 
//Executre our SQL query.
$statement->execute();
 
//Fetch all of the rows from our MySQL table.
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
//Get the column names.
$columnNames = array();
if(!empty($rows)){
    //We only need to loop through the first row of our result
    //in order to collate the column names.
    $firstRow = $rows[0];
    foreach($firstRow as $colName => $val){
        $columnNames[] = $colName;
    }
}
 
//Setup the filename that our CSV will have when it is downloaded.
$fileName = 'mysql-export.csv';
 
//Set the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers to force the download.

    
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mysql-export.csv");
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
 
//Open up a file pointer
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
 
//Start off by writing the column names to the file.
fputcsv($fp, $columnNames);
 
//Then, loop through the rows and write them to the CSV file.
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
 
//Close the file  pointer.
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: with INTO OUTFILE you can make mysql output a csv

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: it wouldn't help you with your problem, so it doesn't really matter in  this context. your are better served with https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-file-download.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers should be:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mysql-export.csv"');
```

Note that it's "text/csv", not "application/csv". And you shouldn't need the other two (application/octet-stream and application/force-download). I hope that helps.

Comment: I still cannot seem to get anything to download. Is there a server change that needs to be made? The data just displays on the browser screen.

Comment: Can you try adding this: header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');

Comment: Cache issue? :)

Comment: Yes! I appreciate your help, do you mind taking a look at the other question I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747401/issue-attaching-csv-export-to-phpmail-script-php